# Fixed Length Flat file Parsing

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, flat-file

I have a flat file tables say, student.tbl and employee.tbl. Both files are fixed length files. I have a supporting files for both files with the information field code, field description, field Offset and field size.

for example,

```
ename string 0 10
eage number 10 2
ecity string 12 10
```

I wrote code to fetch data from the flat files using STL in c++. I am using vector to load those data.

My simple algorithm to load data from Fixed Length file.

> 1) Read Supporting file.
>
> 2) Load supporting file data into a 2D vector string say,
>   column_records;
>
> 3) Read Table file.
>
> 4) Get First Line from the Table File, say Data Line.
>
> 5) Get First Column Information from the supporting Table Which is
>   First Row of column_records.
>
> 6) Chop Data Line based on the column_record
>
> 7) Push the chopped data into a One Dimensional Vector say,
>   record_vector.
>
> 8) Do Step 5, Until the Last Column Information has processed.
>
> 9) Push record_vector into 2D vector say,Table_Vector.
>
> 10) Do Step 4, Until the last line of the Fixed File has reached.

Well. I did it well. It works fine. But my problem is, in Step 5.

For every fixed length data, I feel there was some repeat Iterations.
I know for a fact, First Fixed Length data itself can have retain the column descriptions for other fixed length data. But I repeatedly doing the Iteration N*M. I wish to my iteration should be 1*M.

I know that I can store my column description in a Structure array. But I have many type of tables. say students.tbl and employee.tbl. Both have different set of columns. So I think it will be bad Idea to have 'N'-struct declaration to load 'N'-supporting Tables.

I wish to use same routine to fetch data from the both tables or 'N' tables. My supporting table format will not be changed. It is in tab delimited format. This is my case.

How do I fetch data from table with 1*M iteration?

I hope I can use enumeration to do this. But I don't know how to do that? will using enumeration or macro solve this issue?

I hope my working source code will not be needed for this Question. If you think source code are needed to answer this question, definitely I will update this question with that source code. I have medium level of English Knowledge. So Sorry for Inconvenience.

Thank You.

Comment: That's not *fixed length*. If it was fixed length, each line and each field of each line would be of fixed unchanging length.

Comment: As for parsing the file, it's very simple: Read each line into a `std::istringstream` and use the normal "input" operator `>>` to read each field of the line.

Comment: With the use of std::istringstream, how can I chop 10th Position to 12th Position from the string.